# Insert lines at the end of a block with ansible.builtin.lineinfile

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to add a couple of config items to the default containerd config file. Here is a snippet of the file.

```
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.default_runtime]
        runtime_type = ""
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.untrusted_workload_runtime]
        runtime_type = ""
        runtime_engine = ""
        runtime_root = ""
        privileged_without_host_devices = false
      [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]
        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v1"
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
    [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]
```

I want to insert the following two lines at the end of `[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc]` block.

```
          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]
            SystemdCgroup = true
```

I've managed to insert them at the beginning of the block with the following code. It's messy and I'm manually counting the whitespaces which I want to avoid. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
---
- name: Replace line in file
  hosts: control
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Replacing first line
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /root/config.toml
        insertafter: '^(\s+)\[plugins.+\w\.runc\]'
        line: '          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.runc.options]'
    - name: Replacing second line
      ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
        path: /root/config.toml
        insertafter: '^(\s+)\[plugins.+\w\.runc\.options\]'
        line: '            SystemdCgroup = true'
```

I tried working with `backrefs` but ended up replacing instead of adding.

Comment: Seems using `insertbefore: '[plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".cni]'` should work.

Comment: @Jack Yeah, I thought of that and that seems to be the simplest solution for the current situation. But if the file changes then I'll end up adding it some where I didn't mean to. I was wondering if there was a more logical way of saying find this block and stick these lines at the end.

Comment: I think, this isn't possible, because lineinfile is line-based. But you want to add it after a block (a list of lines) that starts with a known line. All you can do, is a `insertbefore` in that case. Other option: Read in the whole file into a structure (with a new module) and then operate on that structure. Python isn't that complicated.

Comment: @Rohan Then use a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there is no logical way of doing this yet. The best solutions seem to be either to use a template (seems to be the preferred way) or use `insertbefore`.